# In which situation, We can used android service?

Tags: android, android-service, background-process, android-service-binding

I am new in Android. I wanted to know about Android Service. My question is How can i used Android Service? 
When to used exactly for back ground means which type of TASK may used to create service? 
anybody can tell.

Comment: Google has lot of answers for this question. Please do some initial research before asking question here. Happy googling! :-)

Comment: Services are used for playing media files, downloading / doing network operations or long computations.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of service comes to picture when you want to do some work which do not require UI and that runs regularly. Lets take an example. You show a list of comments in an activity and you want to check for the new comments regularly and alert user about it. For this, you can use the service which regularly check for update and once you get the new update, then you can alert user about it(Though you can use cloud messaging for this, I used it just for real world example).

Answer (score 1):

These are the tasks that do not really need necessarily to be visible to the user. A good example is playing music. You don't need to keep the player screen for the song to play....That is it just can play a song as the user works on other applications. Another example is downloading... I don't need to see as the download takes place. It just can be done without me as the user realizing it actually is happening.... that is on the background. In your application you use services to run those tasks that you don't what to get hold of the UI, in the background as services.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know about service there is a lot of material that you can find on the internet. If you don't know anything start with studying material from developer website of android.

Please study [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [Creating a Background Service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) for learning about service.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Services are used for long running tasks, especially those, that run when your activity is not running. Basically you implement Service to perform task where Activity presence in foreground is not that required. Like playing music in background and you do any other things. Or Another e.g. would be you want to check server for any updates even if your activity is not active. You can google out for more e.gs

Basic links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

When you explore more, you will understand the other uses of services.